# a NoMethodError when trying to display time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, error-handling

I am having a unique problem with rails. I am currently trying to run this code..

```
<%= trip.start_date.strftime("%b %d %I:%M %p") %>
```

And when I have my framework timezone set to UTC it will output the start_date correctly. But, when I change the timezone to EST/EDT it gives me a `NoMethodError for nil:NilClass` error.

When I check the database for the trips, it is storing the time for the `start_date` correctly, but doesn't seem to want to format it, or display it.

Hope that makes sense, thanks!

EDIT:
Also, in application.rb i've written

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

and afterward, I reset the database then reset the server.

SOLVED! Thank you to Miler

I changed `config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'` to `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timezone should be set like this in **application.rb**

```
module Spatravlr
  class Application < Rails::Application
     # code
     config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
  end
end
```

Next, let's make the application control for `nil` cases so we can work with the error.

```
<%= trip.start_date.try(:strftime, "%b %d %I:%M %p") %>
```

Given the `trip` attributes seems to be part of an iterator, this fix should also reveal which `start_date` is `nil` when it prints out the times.

Also, you don't need:

```
 config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

I believe since Rails 3.2, that accepts `:local` or `:utc`. So, you can set either not declare it (remove the line), or set it like this:

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Comment: Yep, the timezone has been set like that already, and I have reset the server, and reset the database with the new timezone, but it still doesn't want to work.

Comment: i've written, `config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
    config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'`

Comment: What is the database field type for `start_date`? Also, change this line: `<%= trip.start_date.strftime("%b %d %I:%M %p") %> ` to `<%= trip.start_date.nil? %>` and second line for `<%= trip.nil? %>`  and please tell me what the output is.

Comment: `<%= trip.start_date.nil? %>`, returned true, but when I view the database it clearly has a time in the start_date column. The database field type is datetime. EDIT: `<%= trip.nil? %>` returned false, sorry didn't see it before.

Comment: No worries, I added the second part after the first. I added some code that will make the application workable while we sort through this. Please apply that code for now. Then we can figure out why `start_date` is nil. But that code will fix the original error.

Comment: cool cool, yea it fixes the original error, now we just need to find out why the application doesn't want to read anything from the database. My first thought is that SQL databases will store time in UTC, not EST. Which makes me think that when extracting from the database, the application doesn't know what to do with the time it's given since it's in UTC. Also, all start_dates are nil.

Comment: edited. i think the problem is:  `config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I did not know that change after Rails 3.2, I had actually just updated my rails from rails 3 about a week ago.